# Executing function when subscribing to an event

Tags: c#, events

Is it possible to execute some code when someone subscribes to an event that i made in my class. a short explenation: i need to configure an external pc to send data to me when someone subscribes to this event, so when that data is received i can throw the event.

```
public class test
        {
            public event EventHandler myEvent;

            private void Method1()
            { 
                //this needs to be executed when someone subscribes to the event
            }

            private void Method2()
            {
                //this needs to be executed when someone unsubscribes to the event
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your `add` / `remove` methods

```
 private EventHandler myEvent;
    public event EventHandler MyEvent {
        add {
            myEvent += value;
            if(myEvent != null) ExecuteCode();
        }
        remove {
            myEvent -= value;
        }
    }
```

be careful if your function should be thread-safe, in which case you need a lock in order to ensure it to be synched.