# Fire an event when an event is subscribed to

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have a class that implements an event that will fire on inactivity.

```
public event EventHandler Inactivity;
```

Now, I only want to check for inactivity, when there is subscriber to the event Inactivity. So is there any way to fire an event when it has been subscribed to?

I thought of something like this:

```
Inactivity.Subscription += OnInactivitySubscription

private void OnInactivitySubscription(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartActivityCheck();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477948/executing-function-when-subscribing-to-an-event).

```
public event EventHandler Inactivity
{
    add
    {
        Inactivity += value;
        if (!IsAlreadyCheckingForActivity)
        {
            StartActivityCheck();
        }
                
    }
    remove
    {
        Inactivity -= value;
    }
}
```

"Be careful if your function should be thread-safe, in which case you need a lock in order to ensure it to be synched."